# Нажать на кнопку PyQt5 ,так чтобы исполнился скрипт из другого файла "py"

Tags: python, pyqt5

Хотел сделать так чтобы при нажатии кнопки **button** запускался скрипт из другого файла **test1.py**
Проблема в том ,что при запуске программы сначала вылезает браузер,делает все из файла test1.py,а потом выскакивает программа и при нажатии на кнопку уже ничего не происходит.....
Заранее извиняюсь за дилетантизм(только начал все это изучать....)

Основной код (где кнопка и т.д...)

```js
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton
import test1


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Простая программммммма")  # Основное окно
        self.setGeometry(300, 250, 350, 200)
        self.button = QPushButton('Начать скрипт', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.nagatie)

    def nagatie(self):
        a = exec("test1.py")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код из test1.py

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument('-profile')
options.add_argument(r'C:\Users\werty\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\6w07oelt.proffffffff')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)


def proverka_vxoda():
    driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/")
    print("начало")


proverka_vxoda()


driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/")
print("проверка")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно обернуть код из **test1.py** в функцию

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

def run():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('-profile')
    options.add_argument(r'C:\Users\werty\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\6w07oelt.proffffffff')
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)


    def proverka_vxoda():
        driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/")
        print("начало")


    proverka_vxoda()


    driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/")
    print("проверка")
```

И вызывать эту функцию при нажатии на кнопку

```py
def nagatie(self):
    test1.run()
```

Либо так:

```py
import os
...
def nagatie(self):
    os.system('python test1.py')
```

Comment: Это я уже так эксперемнтировал.... Да так (когда в функуции) все нормально и корректно. Но можно как то чтобы это НЕ через функцию...? Чтобы указать файл и он начал исполнятся?

Comment: P, s всё равно спасибо огромное за подсказку

Comment: os.system('python test1.py')  так то что нужно!!! БлагоДарю TheBotGames ! Плюс Немножко доработал -  нужно было убрать сам импорт в начале основного файла import test1. С ним все равно открывает в начале браузер ,а потом проходится по коду из  test1 почему то